# Find the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$ in both the domain and the codomain

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

$T : V \to V$ be defined by $T(p(x)) = p(0) + p(1)x$.

Any hints on this one?

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried? Can you tell us $T(s)$ where $s$ is each of the three basis polynomials, for example?

Comment: Forgot to mention p(0)= 0,Is it something like T(1) = p(1), T(x)= p(1)x, T(x^2) = p(1)x^2?  @John

Comment: @user164945 You can take $p(x)=1$, after that $p(x)=x$, and finally $p(x)=x^2$. Do you can finish?

Comment: @DiegoMath Sorry I am really new to this topic and always get confused how to do this. Are you saying when i take p(x) =1, no matter what value is inside the bracket, the p part is always 1 so answers are 1+x, x+x^2, x^2+x^3?

Comment: No, the answer is $1+x,x,x$.

Comment: Look my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix that you looking for is
$$A=\left[T(1)\ T(x)\ T(x^2)\right].$$

1. $T(1)=1+x$
2. $T(x)=0+x=x$
3. $T(x^2)=0+x=x$

So 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

An example is take $p(x)=1+3x^2$, then
$$T(p(x))=p(0)+p(1)x=1+4x.$$
By other hand,
$$T(p(x))=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1+3\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}=1+4x.$$

I hope you understanding the whole answer!

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood everything except the part where T(1) = 1+x, T(x)=0+x=x , T(x^2)= 0+x = x, maybe I am missing something, I just can't figure out how you get that.

Comment: As in my early comment, it's just take $p(x)=1$, after that $p(x)=x$, and finally $p(x)=x^2$. Note that if $p(x)=1$ then $p(0)=p(1)=1$, the other cases are similar.

Comment: Finally I get it now! Sometimes I find it hard to get my head around these little things. Many thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, You will learn this things and much more in your life, have a good time.